# Como mostrar a mensagem de feedback apenas para o campo focado?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou realizando uma verificação usando `jquery` com o intuito de aplicar esse método em um projeto futuro mais elaborado. Não há nenhum problema com o script, o que eu preciso é: Ao começar digitar no campo `nome` por exemplo, apareça o feedback apenas para ele e não para os demais como está ocorrendo.

Abaixo estou deixando o código pois ficará mais fácil de simular, basta digitar algo em algum dos campos e verificar que o feedback aparecerá para todos, mas o esperado é aparecer apenas para o campo focado.

```js
$('#form-cadastro input').focus( function(){
   $(this).on('input', function() {
    validarCampos();       
   });
  }); 
  var nome = $('#nome');
  var email = $('#email');
  var  validarCampos = function() {
   var valido = true;
   if (nome.val() == "" || nome.val().length < 5) { 
    campoIncorreto('nome', 'Campo nome preenchido incorretamente!');        
    valido = false;
   } else {     
    campoCorreto('nome', 'Campo nome preenchido corretamente!');    
   }
   if (email.val() == "" || email.val().length < 5) {
    campoIncorreto('email', 'Campo email preenchido incorretamente!');
    valido = false;
   } else {
    campoCorreto('email', 'Campo preenchido corretamente!');
   }
   if (valido == true) {
    return true;
   } else {
    return false;
   }
  }
  
  
  var campoCorreto = function(nome, texto) { 
   //campo input, usa-se sempre o id do elemento   
   $('#'+nome).removeClass('is-invalid');
   $('#'+nome).addClass('is-valid');
   
   //campo de feedback
   $('#feedback-'+nome).removeClass('invalid-feedback');
   $('#feedback-'+nome).addClass('valid-feedback');
   $('#feedback-'+nome).text(texto).show("slow");   
  }
  
  
  var campoIncorreto = function(nome, texto) {
   //campo input, usa-se sempre o id do elemento
   $('#'+nome).removeClass('is-valid');
   $('#'+nome).addClass('is-invalid');
   
   //campo de feedback
   $('#feedback-'+nome).removeClass('valid-feedback');
   $('#feedback-'+nome).addClass('invalid-feedback');
   $('#feedback-'+nome).text(texto).show("slow");
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
  integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
    div.main {
   margin:50px 16%;
    }   
  </style>
<div class="container">
      <div class="main col-8 offset-2">
                <form id="form-cadastro" method="POST" action="https://www.google.com" onsubmit="return validarCampos()">
     <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="nome" id="nome" />
     <span id="feedback-nome">  </span> <br>   
     <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="email" id="email" />
     <span id="feedback-email"></span> <br>
     <input class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="submit" value="Enviar"/>   
         </form>
   </div>
  </div>
  <script 
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" 
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" 
  crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
  integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Envie para a função `validarCampos` o elemento que está sendo digitado:

```
validarCampos($(this));
```

Na função você recebe o elemento como parâmetro:

```
var  validarCampos = function(e) {...
```

Esse evento `focus` é dispenável, basta usar apenas o evento `input`:

```
$('#form-cadastro input.form-control').on('input', function() {
   validarCampos($(this));                          
});
```

Adicionei também um `return false;` na função `campoIncorreto`, para parar a função principal quando o campo for inválido.

Também otimizei as funções `campoCorreto` e `campoIncorreto` removendo repetições ao usar múltiplos métodos para o mesmo elemento.

Outras explicações coloquei no código:

```js
$('#form-cadastro input.form-control').on('input', function() {
   validarCampos($(this));       
});

var  validarCampos = function(e) {
   var inps = $('#form-cadastro input');
   for(var x=0; x<inps.length; x++){
      var id = !e ? $(inps[x]) : $('#'+e.attr("id")); // o valor $('#'+e.attr("id")) é se o form for submetido
      if (id.val().length < 5) {
         return campoIncorreto(id.attr('id'), 'Campo '+id.attr('placeholder')+' preenchido incorretamente!');        
      } else {     
         campoCorreto(id.attr('id'), 'Campo '+id.attr('placeholder')+' preenchido corretamente!');
      }
   }

   var valida = $('#form-cadastro input.is-valid').length; // conto o número de campos válidos
   return valida == 2 ? true : false; // e o número de campos válidos for igual a 2, envia
}
  
  
var campoCorreto = function(nome, texto) { 
   //campo input, usa-se sempre o id do elemento   
   $('#'+nome)
   .removeClass('is-invalid')
   .addClass('is-valid');
   
   //campo de feedback
   $('#feedback-'+nome)
   .removeClass('invalid-feedback')
   .addClass('valid-feedback')
   .text(texto)
   .show("slow");   
}

var campoIncorreto = function(nome, texto) {
   //campo input, usa-se sempre o id do elemento
   $('#'+nome)
   .removeClass('is-valid')
   .addClass('is-invalid');
   
   //campo de feedback
   $('#feedback-'+nome)
   .removeClass('valid-feedback')
   .addClass('invalid-feedback')
   .text(texto)
   .show("slow");
   
   return false;
}
```

```css
div.main {
   margin:50px 16%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
    <div class="main col-8 offset-2">
          <form id="form-cadastro" method="POST" action="https://www.google.com" onsubmit="return validarCampos()">
         <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="nome" id="nome" />
         <span id="feedback-nome">  </span> <br>   
         <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="email" id="email" />
         <span id="feedback-email"></span> <br>
         <input class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="submit" value="Enviar"/>   
       </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Eu tinha feito desse jeito, mas ele permite o submit mesmo estando fora do padrão estabelecido nas regras

Comment: Eu percebi, estou reformulando o código.

Comment: Veja agora. Tive que fazer alterações drásticas porque estava conflitando o submit e o digitar no campo. Dois eventos usando a mesma função é complicado.

Comment: Muito bom, obrigado :D

Comment: mais uma dúvida: `var inps = $('input', '#form-cadastro');` = `var inps = $( '#form-cadastro input');` ?

Comment: Verdade, é a mesma coisa. Alterei na resposta.

Comment: obrigado pela resposta :)

Answer (score 0):

Você tem que adicionar um return quando identificado que campo não está válido.

```
if (nome.val() == "" || nome.val().length < 5) {    
                campoIncorreto('nome', 'Campo nome preenchido incorretamente!');                                
                return false;
            } else {                
                campoCorreto('nome', 'Campo nome preenchido corretamente!');                
            }
            if (email.val() == "" || email.val().length < 5) {
                campoIncorreto('email', 'Campo email preenchido incorretamente!');
                return false;
            } else {
                campoCorreto('email', 'Campo preenchido corretamente!');
            }
```

Comment: Se eu colocar return, ele irá validar apenas o primeiro campo a ser digitado